# how to check if mount is soft NFS

Tags: networking, mount, nfs

I'm looking for a command to check if a nfs folder is mounted soft, my fstab is:

```
10.10.1.3:/home/share3     /home/share3  nfs    soft  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mount` command to show all your mounts (or look at `/etc/mtab`), the `grep` command to select your specific mount, then another `grep` to check for `soft`:

```
mount | grep /home/share3 | grep -q soft
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "/home/share3 is mounted with 'soft'"
else
    echo "/home/share3 is not mounted with 'soft'"
fi
```

Comment: Even better would be `/proc/mount` as it always lists all mount points as seen by the kernel in a machine-readable format.

Answer (score 2):

Although I probably would have used `mount` (as described in [walinator's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008405/178692)) myself, according to `man mount` we should get out of the habit:

> ```
>    The listing.
>           The listing mode is maintained for backward compatibility only.
>
>           For more robust and customizable output  use  findmnt(8),  espe‐
>           cially  in  your  scripts.
> ```

The `findmnt` command gives a bit more flexibility as well - for example you can find either by source or target directly (without needing to `grep`), and output just the filesystem-specific options. Compare:

```
$ mount -t nfs | grep public
192.168.1.127:/c/public on /mnt/nfs/public type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.1.127,mountvers=3,mountport=3097,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.127)
```

to

```
$ findmnt -nM /mnt/nfs/public  -oFS-OPTIONS
rw,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.1.127,mountvers=3,mountport=3097,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.127
```

I don't think it (yet) provides a way to get values of specific options directly, so a `grep` or `awk` would still be necessary for that.

```
$ findmnt -nM /mnt/nfs/public  -oFS-OPTIONS | grep -qE '\bsoft\b' && echo "soft" || echo "hard"
hard
```

In your case, it would be

```
findmnt -nM /home/share3 -oFS-OPTIONS | grep -qE '\bsoft\b' && echo "soft" || echo "hard"
```